# how to populate xml elements from a complex type array element in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0, soa

I have an xml of the following structure.

```
<DATA_DS>
    <G_2>
        <INFORMATION_TYPE>A</INFORMATION_TYPE>
        <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>101</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
        <FIRST_NAME>X</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Y</LAST_NAME>
        <RESPONSIBILITY>Responsibility 1</RESPONSIBILITY>
    </G_2>
    <G_2>
        <INFORMATION_TYPE>A</INFORMATION_TYPE>
        <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>101</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
        <FIRST_NAME>X</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Y</LAST_NAME>
        <RESPONSIBILITY>Responsibility 2</RESPONSIBILITY>
    </G_2>
    <G_2>
        <INFORMATION_TYPE>A</INFORMATION_TYPE>
        <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>101</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
        <FIRST_NAME>X</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Y</LAST_NAME>
        <RESPONSIBILITY>Responsibility 3</RESPONSIBILITY>
    </G_2>
    <G_2>
        <INFORMATION_TYPE>B</INFORMATION_TYPE>
        <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>101</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
        <FIRST_NAME>X</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>Y</LAST_NAME>
        <RESPONSIBILITY>Responsibility 1</RESPONSIBILITY>
    </G_2>
    <G_2>
        <INFORMATION_TYPE>A</INFORMATION_TYPE>
        <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>102</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
        <FIRST_NAME>M</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>N</LAST_NAME>
        <RESPONSIBILITY>Responsibility 1</RESPONSIBILITY>
    </G_2>
    <G_2>
        <INFORMATION_TYPE>A</INFORMATION_TYPE>
        <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>102</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
        <FIRST_NAME>M</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>N</LAST_NAME>
        <RESPONSIBILITY>Responsibility 2</RESPONSIBILITY>
    </G_2>
    <G_2>
        <INFORMATION_TYPE>A</INFORMATION_TYPE>
        <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>102</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
        <FIRST_NAME>M</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>N</LAST_NAME>
        <RESPONSIBILITY>Responsibility 2</RESPONSIBILITY>
    </G_2>
</DATA_DS>
```

I have a requirement to create an output xml for each employee in the following format

```
<EMP>
    <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>101</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
    <FIRST_NAME>X</FIRST_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Y</LAST_NAME>
    <RESPONSIBILITY1>Driving</RESPONSIBILITY1>
    <RESPONSIBILITY2>Cooking</RESPONSIBILITY2>
    <RESPONSIBILITY3>Cleaning</RESPONSIBILITY3>
    <RESPONSIBILITY4></RESPONSIBILITY4>
    <RESPONSIBILITY5></RESPONSIBILITY5>
    <RESPONSIBILITY6></RESPONSIBILITY6>
</EMP>
<EMP>
    <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>102</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
    <FIRST_NAME>M</FIRST_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>N</LAST_NAME>
    <RESPONSIBILITY1>Driving</RESPONSIBILITY1>
    <RESPONSIBILITY2>Singing</RESPONSIBILITY2>
    <RESPONSIBILITY3></RESPONSIBILITY3>
    <RESPONSIBILITY4></RESPONSIBILITY4>
    <RESPONSIBILITY5></RESPONSIBILITY5>
    <RESPONSIBILITY6></RESPONSIBILITY6>
</EMP>
```

I am using group-by to group the input xml by employee number .
For population RESPONSIBILITY1,2 tags I have to check INFORMATION_TYPE for each employee. Only when INFORMATION_TYPE is A INFORMATION_TYPE = 'A' ,I have to populate RESPONSIBILITY1 and succeeding  tags in the output for the particular employee. For other INFORMATION_TYPE (ex B) i don't need to take the RESPONSILITY value.
(In the example output employee 101 has INFORMATION TYPE A and B , but my requirement is to take RESPONSIBILITY value from only A)

So for employee 101 we have 3 responsibilities Driving, Cooking and Cleaning as INFORMATION TYPE is A.

Similarly for employee 102 we have 2 responsibilities Driving and Singing .

We don't need Values for responsibility when INFORMATION TYPE is not A for an employee.

I have used group-by  employee number which groups my input by employee number. I have further grouped the current group by INFORMATION_TYPE . I am unable to populate the RESPONSIBILITY tags in output. How can I achieve the above in XSLT?

XSLT

```
<EMPLOYEES>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="DATA_DS/G_2" group-by="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER">
        <EMP>
            <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
                <xsl:value-of select="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER"/>
            </EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
            <FIRST_NAME>
                <xsl:value-of select="FIRST_NAME"/>
            </FIRST_NAME>
            <LAST_NAME>
                <xsl:value-of select="LAST_NAME"/>
            </LAST_NAME>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group() [INFORMATION_TYPE ='A']">
                <RESPONSIBILITY1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="RESPONSIBILITY[1]"/>
                </RESPONSIBILITY1>
                <RESPONSIBILITY2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="RESPONSIBILITY[2]"/>
                </RESPONSIBILITY2>
                <RESPONSIBILITY3>
                    <xsl:value-of select="RESPONSIBILITY[3]"/>
                </RESPONSIBILITY3>
                <RESPONSIBILITY4>
                    <xsl:value-of select="RESPONSIBILITY[4]"/>
                </RESPONSIBILITY4>
                <RESPONSIBILITY5>
                    <xsl:value-of select="RESPONSIBILITY[4]"/>
                </RESPONSIBILITY5>
                <RESPONSIBILITY6>
                    <xsl:value-of select="RESPONSIBILITY[4]"/>
                </RESPONSIBILITY6>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </EMP>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</EMPLOYEES>
```

Comment: Consider to present the input sample in a well-formatted and readable and clean XML format; then also add your current XSLT together with the result it produces and explain in more detail what has to happen with input data where e.g. `INFORMATION_TYPE` is not `A` but `B` or some other value, do you want to drop that data completely or just not add the `RESPONSIBILITYx` elements in that case?

Comment: Hi Martin , have edited the original question . When INFORMATION_TYPE is anything else then A then i don't want that data to be populated in RESPONSIBILITYx tags. RESPONSIBILITYx tags should only be populated for employee with INFORMATION_TYPE as A. There are total of 6 RESPONSIBILTYx tags in the output and should be populated everytime. In case of there are 3 RESPONSIBLITIES for INFORMATION TYPE A i should populate  RESPONSIBILITY1,RESPONSIBILITY2, RESPONSIBILITY3 and rest of three i have to set as empty values.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `<xsl:for-each select="current-group() [INFORMATION_TYPE ='A']">..</xsl:for-each>` you simply want e.g.

```
        <xsl:variable name="responsibilities" select="current-group()[INFORMATION_TYPE ='A']/RESPONSIBILITY"/>
        <xsl:if test="current-group()[INFORMATION_TYPE ='A']">
            <RESPONSIBILITY1>
                <xsl:value-of select="$responsibilities[1]"/>
            </RESPONSIBILITY1>
            <RESPONSIBILITY2>
                <xsl:value-of select="$responsibilities[2]"/>
            </RESPONSIBILITY2>
            <RESPONSIBILITY3>
                <xsl:value-of select="$responsibilities[3]"/>
            </RESPONSIBILITY3>
            <RESPONSIBILITY4>
                <xsl:value-of select="$responsibilities[4]"/>
            </RESPONSIBILITY4>
            <RESPONSIBILITY5>
                <xsl:value-of select="$responsibilities[5]"/>
            </RESPONSIBILITY5>
            <RESPONSIBILITY6>
                <xsl:value-of select="$responsibilities[6]"/>
            </RESPONSIBILITY6>
        </xsl:if>
```

as far as I can tell.

Comment: thanks Martin , it works for my requirement :) ,  any pointers where I can learn more about xslt.

Comment: There are lots of resources, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-2.0/info list a free book on XSLT 2 and an online course (that is usually not free but I think Pluralsight offers some free trial and also have some kind of free week of access coming up every spring). There are lots of other books also courses, check your favourite book seller or course site. Only the current version XSLT 3.0 is not well and extensively covert by books but the major two vendors Saxonica and Altova have good online documentation.